# How to display Asp.net Identity cookie expire popup in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, owin, identity

I have MVC 5 web API application which uses Asp.net identity for authentication and Authorization.This is single page application and user can login using email and password.I have to show session expires popup if user idle for some time.

I have tried using Session.Timeout in web.config. It doesn't work because, my application wont refresh. All client communicates server using AJAX.

How can I show session expire pop up based on cookies time out?

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        string expireTimeConfig = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExpireTime"];
        int expireTimeSpan = Convert.ToInt32(expireTimeConfig);
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieName = "APP",
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(expireTimeSpan),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                //  OnValidateIdentity = MyCustomValidateIdentity, //refer to the implementation below
                //    OnValidateIdentity = ImpersonatingSecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, User>(
                //validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                //regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user)),

                OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                {
                    if (!IsApiRequest(ctx.Request))
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                    }
                },
                OnResponseSignIn = ctx =>
                {
                    var ticks = ctx.Options.SystemClock.UtcNow.AddHours(10).UtcTicks;
                    ctx.Properties.Dictionary.Add("absolute", ticks.ToString());
                },
                OnValidateIdentity = ctx =>
                {
                    bool reject = true;
                    string value;
                    if (ctx.Properties.Dictionary.TryGetValue("absolute", out value))
                    {
                        long ticks;
                        if (Int64.TryParse(value, out ticks))
                        {
                            reject = ctx.Options.SystemClock.UtcNow.UtcTicks > ticks;
                        }
                    }

                    if (reject)
                    {
                        ctx.RejectIdentity();
                        // optionally clear cookie
                        ctx.OwinContext.Authentication.SignOut(ctx.Options.AuthenticationType);
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }

            },


        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);


        if (Convert.ToBoolean(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OAuth"].ToString()))
        {
            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["microsoftClientId"].ToString(),
                ClientSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["microsoftClientSecret"].ToString(),
                Scope =
            {
                "wl.basic", "wl.emails"
            }
            });

            app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
               consumerKey: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"].ToString(),
               consumerSecret: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"].ToString());

            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AppId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppId"].ToString(),
                AppSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppSecret"].ToString(),
                Scope = { "email" }
            });

            var options = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleClientId"].ToString(),
                ClientSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleClientSecret"].ToString(),
                Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = async context =>
                    {
                        string accessToken = context.AccessToken;

                        // Retrieve the name of the user in Google
                        string googleName = context.Name;

                        // Retrieve the user's email address
                        string googleEmailAddress = context.Email;

                        // You can even retrieve the full JSON-serialized user
                        var serializedUser = context.User;
                    }
                }
            };

            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(options);

            app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(
                clientId: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["linkedInClientId"].ToString(),
                clientSecret: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["linkedInClientSecret"].ToString());

            app.UseYahooAuthentication(consumerKey: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["yahooConsumerKey"].ToString(),
                consumerSecret: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["yahooConsumerSecret"].ToString());

        }

        // app.UseKentorAuthServicesAuthentication(CreateAuthServicesOptions( ));

        app.MapSignalR();


    }
```

How can i read ExpireTimeSpan on the client and shows session time out popup?

Answer (score 1):

Basically add onload to your body tag calling StartTimers(). You can also add an onmousemove to the body tag which calls ResetTimer() so that as long as there is activity on the page a timeout is not triggered. If no mouse activity is seen on the page the dialog is displayed if movement is detected the dialog is closed and the timers reset.

Example:

```js
// Set timeout variables.
var timoutWarning = 60000; // Display warning in 1Mins.
var timoutNow = 120000; // Timeout in 2 mins.
var logoutUrl = 'http://www.asp.net; // URL to logout page.

var warningTimer;
var timeoutTimer;

// Start timers.
function StartTimers() {
    warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
}

// Reset timers.
function ResetTimers() {
    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
    clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
    StartTimers();
    $("#timeout").dialog('close');
}

// Show idle timeout warning dialog.
function IdleWarning() {
    $("#timeout").dialog({
        modal: true
    });
}

// Logout the user.
function IdleTimeout() {
    window.location = logoutUrl;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="timeout">
        <h1>
            Session About To Timeout</h1>
        <p>
            You will be automatically logged out in 1 minute.<br />
        To remain logged in move your mouse over this window.
    </div>
    <table id="table1" align="center" border="1" width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Hello World
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```